# Migrate data from vertica to MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, vertica

I am trying to migrate vertica table data to mysql for doing some analysis

can we do using any tool ??

If not possible I have basic understanding of PHP

Please suggest.

Comment: Why not perform the analysis on Vertica? It is by far more suited for analysis than MySQL ... Faster, with more possibilities - ; you can just use SQL where you have to program extensively in other databases ....

Answer (score -1):

An easy approach would be :

**1 - Export Table + Data into csv data format**
You can find more about how to export data from Vertica here [Vertica Export](http://www.aodba.com/export-import-table-vertica/)

```
vsql -U dbadmin -w dbadmin -At -c "SELECT EXPORT_TABLES('table_one')" -o /vertica/backup/table_one.sql
vsql -U dbadmin -w dbadmin -F $'|' -At -c "SELECT * FROM table_one" | gzip -c > '/vertica/backup_table_one.gz'
```

**2- Import the csv file into your mysql db using [mysqlimport](http://excel2sql.esy.es/)**
- make sure you unzip before importing :)

```
mysqlimport --ignore-lines=1 \
        --fields-terminated-by=| \
        --local -u root \
         -p Database \
         backup_table_one.csv
```